# Secure user authentication in offline web apps

Tags: javascript, html, security, encryption

This question has cropped up a few times in various guises, but I've not seen an answer that satisfies my requirement or fills me with much confidence. Let me set the scene.

We currently have a web application, which allows users to submit responses to pre-set questions where the data ends up in an SQL Server database, we also have a Windows application that does the same thing but works in an offline capacity; i.e. it connects to the SQL Server, downloads the questions, allows the user to complete them offline and when they next have a network connection they can synchronise the data, uploading it to the SQL Server. Great!

As part of our development strategy, given HTML 5's offline capabilities and local storage,it seems perfectly sensible to attempt to consolidate these products into a single web application. This would mean we're able to work on a single code base, and this would also enable the application to run in a browser on most devices; platform independent.

Looking into this I see a couple of potential problems, I'd really appreciate a steer on these:

1. Users need the ability to login, in offline and on-line modes. This could mean we download the hash's of the all users usernames and passwords, or just those that have logged in whilst in on-line mode. However, even doing this there needs to be a way to check these and given that the Javascript is readable someone could easily reverse engineer their credentials. Yes you can obfuscate the code but this isn't infallible.
2. The data that needs to be stored locally could be highly sensitive; contain personal information etc. Therefore this also needs encrypting, at minimum AES 256.

Am I hoping for utopia? Is this something that's just not possible at this time? Do I need to be looking at another solution and dismissing this for the time being?

Any help from you lovely people would be much appreciated.

Comment: `"Am I hoping for utopia? Is this something that's just not possible at this time? Do I need to be looking at another solution and dismissing this for the time being?"` In my opinion, Yes, Yes and Yes.

Comment: :grin: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

First the easier question 2: that is perfectly possible. You can generate the key on the device and on sync send it via https to your server which can decrypt the data then.

As for question 1 I'd say an offline login is not really feasible BUT do you actually need one? Once the questionaire is downloaded (which requires online mode, so requiring login is fine) you only need to transmit it on sync, where online is again required and you can ask the user for his login there, too. I'd not recommend to download any sensible user data (e.g. hashes) to the device.

Comment: In response: 1. Yes, I'm afraid so, the users may share a device and as data may persist which might be confidential, each user shouldn't be able to see anyone else's data, so this is a must. Also users may also go out into the community and collect information about about multiple Patients (many records) they could potentially loose the device. If it gets into the wrong hands with patient confidential information on it IG will go crazy the ICO will have a field day!

Comment: 2. Again as with 1, the encryption would need to be stored on the device and we'd have the same issue with looking at the JavaScript to reverse engineer the credentials.

Comment: The encryption part would have to be done in Java, Cordova provides excellent support for calling Java functions from Javascript. This way you also use the user space of the app which is normally not readable by other apps.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I would rather try to do this without using any commercial products, i.e. it be standards based. Any ideas other than what you've already said?

Comment: Oh, I see it's open source, I'm afraid that won't float either - picky aren't I!!!

Comment: If you really want to do it in pure HTML/JS you'll probably have to wait for http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/ though from a quick scan of the document I'm not sure if even this will provide the necessary functionality.

Comment: @StuieM The crypto api has browser support. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to cache the current user only after logging in online. This would mitigate the risk of enumerating the users in your local DB.

You then need to encrypt the user's data on the front-end, I'd go with a library that does the job for you (for example, RxDB). RxDB accepts a password (which you can generate on the fly) and based on it, encrypts your DB data. The user then fills in the form (does whatever he wants) and if all of the sudden the internet is gone, the user is still able to continue his work and that work must be added as pending requests in order to do the sync. (which you already have)

When the internet is restored, you're going to check whether the session has expired for the user and if so, prompt the user to log in again and do the sync if it was the same user. If it's still there, perform the sync.

Answer (score 0):

My advice based on my personal experience for the offline part.
You can create a local variable that allows the user to login once using internet for the first time then he will be able to auto login for several times as much as you decided in the local variable and when the value is 0 he will need an internet again to get another offline access for the same value you decided before.

so, in a small words. offline counter that will need an internet Only after many offline logins (when the counter decrease to 0)

[Flowcharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tbpK.png)

Comment: Please add more info to your answer. You can make it more presentable by adding workflow diagram.